# How to create an image hover fade effect with jQuery and CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, hover, fadein, fadeout

I am trying to create a logo hover effect by fading in and out two images. I tried using CSS, but the results did not look as good as expected (even though it works perfectly for other purposes), so I decided to try jQuery as well. (Ignore the tags, they're for blogger).

This was my first approach (which looked good when it came to fading, but 'display: none' was not properly becoming 'display: block' when hovering on it the first time, so the image moved from its initial position. Then it goes back to that position and when hovering it works perfectly.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
$('#MyLogoContainer').hover(function() {
    $('#MyLogoHover').fadeIn('slow');
    $('#MyLogo').fadeOut('slow');  
}, function() { 
    $('#MyLogo').fadeIn('slow'); 
    $('#MyLogoHover').fadeOut('slow');   
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

My second approach solved the CSS position issue, but the animation doesn't look fluid at all and both images disappear almost completely at some point, which doesn't look good and didn't happen with my fist approach.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
$(function() {
$('#MyLogoContainer').hover(function() {
    $('#MyLogoHover').fadeIn('slow').css('display','block');
    $('#MyLogo').fadeOut('slow').css('display','none');  
}, function() { 
    $('#MyLogo').fadeIn('slow').css('display','block'); 
    $('#MyLogoHover').fadeOut('slow').css('display','none');   
});
});
//]]>
</script>
```

The problem's got to be in the CSS. Somehow, I have to find a way so the display property doesn't play a crucial role in positioning any of these two SVG images, so I can use the first jQuery code without any change occurring to my SVG images' position.

```
#MyLogoContainer {
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -350px;
    position: absolute;
}
#MyLogo {
    width: 700px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
}

#MyLogoHover {
    width: 700px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: if you want a javascript approach, jQuery will make this much easier. Otherwise, you can use css transitions by changing the class of the element you want to fade. We need to see more code to be able to help though. What does the HTML look like?

Comment: To fade one image into another, both images have to be displayed at the same time while fading. Create two images, one on top of the other. When  the one on top should disappear, set CSS `opacity` to 0, use CSS `transition`.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/mvw9xm89/1/ <-- a couple examples

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I am going to use jQuery, it's very easy compared to doing the JavaScript myself and the result looks better than with CSS.

Comment: Remove the `css()` method calls in both code blocks. Behind the scenes `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` are essentially handling those CSS declarations on an animated timescale so they're unnecessary. Let me know if that works.

Comment: That's what I did first, I added the css() method later. Before what happened is that the first time I hovered over the div, the image that used to be display: none didn't become display: block and move to the right completely. When I move out the mouse, it goes back to the correct place, and if I hover again, it works perfectly fine. It's just the first time I hover, it's so weird. When I inspected element and hovered, I could see how hovering the first time did something different than when I hovered the second time and so on afterwards. No clue what's going on.

Comment: I just did it by setting max-width and max-height for the container div. All solved. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear things worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've described you might not even need JS to do this:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #ccc;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

.container:hover .logo--static-state {
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:hover .logo--hover-state {
  opacity: 1;
}

.logo {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
}

.logo--static-state {
  z-index: 9999;
}

.logo--hover-state {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 9998;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="logo logo--static-state" src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=Static" height=150 width=150>
  <img class="logo logo--hover-state" src="http://placehold.it/150x150?text=Hovered" height=150 width=150>
</div>
```

Comment: It works, but the issue is that both images are transparent SVG and the borders are visible below the static image before hovering. Is there any way to set 0 opacity on the hover image and increase it to 1 when hovering over the static image (just like you decrease the opacity of that one. I think I have a way to do it. Hovering on the container itself, I will try.

Comment: Made changes based on your comment. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I am trying to make a logo hover effect. Before you updated your answer, I tried it with jQuery and got a similar issue. Something is wrong with my CSS code, because 'display: none'; doesn't become 'display: block'; when I fadeIn the hover image for the first time.. And if I add the .css('display', 'block') it just briefly disappears just like with your code, which doesn't look as expected. I will update my question with my CSS and jQuery. If you update your answer, I think you shouldn't remove what you've posted so far, it will surely be useful for someone.